# Inexplicable behaviour of overloaded method using generics

Tags: java, generics

```
class My<T> {

    void overloadMethod(String s) {
        System.out.println("string");
    }

    void overloadMethod(Integer i) {
        System.out.println("integer");
    }

    void overloadMethod(T t) {
        System.out.println("t");
    }
}

public class MyClass01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String o = "abc";
        new My<String>().overloadMethod(o);
    }
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
/MyClass01.java:20: error: reference to overloadMethod is ambiguous
        new My<String>().overloadMethod(o);
                        ^
  both method overloadMethod(String) in My and method overloadMethod(T) in My match
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class My
1 error
```

I was expecting "string" output assuming that type erasure would ensure that the third method would be:

```
    void overloadMethod(Object t) {
        System.out.println("t");
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: Type erasure is a runtime consequence. You are not at runtime. You're at compile-time. It's not `void overloadMethod(Object t)` at compile-time, otherwise generics would provide no constraints at all.

Comment: I presume you would not want to be able to call `new My<String>().overloadMethod(1234)`, right? If it were somehow erased to `Object` at compile-time, you'd be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

By instantiating the ***generic*** *`class MyClass<T>`* into the ***specific*** parameterized type *`new My<String>().overloadMethod(o);`*, you've *effectively* declared two methods with this same signature: *`overloadMethod(String s)`*.

That's what the compiler error is trying to tell you with: „*`error: reference to overloadMethod is ambiguous`*“.

> „*…What am I missing here?…*“

Because you say: „*I was expecting "string" output*“, it sounds like you're mistakenly assuming that your declaration of *`class My<T>`* has somehow imbued your ***non***-generic method *`overloadMethod(String s)`* with the powers of parametric polymorphism. It hasn't.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the `void overloadMethod(T t)`, here T is generic Class, it could be anything, when you declared
`new My<String>()` then T = String
try to comment in the `overloadMethod(String s)`, you will get "t" as output
The ambiguity comes into play since T = String in this case, so the class has 2 methods to call

```
void overloadMethod(String s) =   void overloadMethod(T t)
```

And doesn't know wich one to call

Comment: OK. Buenas dias muchacho.